# SonarQube not publishing the PHP unit test report

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, phpunit

I installed below SonarQube version in Redhat 6 Serer.
Versions :
SonarQube : 6.3
Sonar Runner : 2.3
Sonar PHP Plugin : 2.10.0.2087

My project creates a PHPUnit Test Report in a Directory called "testreports"

sonar.project.properties:

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=Dashboard3
sonar.projectName=Dashboard3
sonar.projectVersion=2.0
#sonar.language=php

#Path to Source
sonar.sources=/pkg/vddfg/oradfg/apache/htdocs/Symfony/src/DB3
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=testReports/get_jfm_bug11s_test.xml

sonar.exclusions=**/Metro-UI-CSS-master/**
```

My Sonar executed successfully, by updating the line as `Analyzing PHPUnit test report: testReports/get_jfm_bug11s_test.xml` but in SonarQube dashboard we unable to find the Test Report.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the JUnit output format for your tests (PHPUnit configuration):

```
<log type="junit" target="tests.xml"/>
```

2) Add "sonar.tests" to your Sonar properties:

```
sonar.tests=/path/to/tests
```